# How to efficiently group items based on a comparison function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a list of items and a comparison function f(item1, item2) which returns a boolean.

I want to generate groups out of these items so that all items in a same group satisfy the condition f(itemi, itemj) === true.

An item can be included in several groups. There is no mimimum size for a group.

I am trying to write an efficient algorithm in javascript (or other language) for that. I thought it would be pretty easy but I am still on it after a day or so...

Any pointer would be highly appreciated!

(the max size of my items array is 1000, if it helps)

Comment: I've tried various things but failed when it came to implement them. For instance I created a matrix of 0 and 1 using all combinations and look for square sub matrixes of 1 by moving columns and lines around, but not easy to implement! an other one was to run on each column (all match for the itemi) and then generate groups in a tree like fashion. I guess my main issue is I don't really have a clear method for tackling the problem and was hoping it would correspond to a well known type of problem/algorithm.

Comment: first of all, is `f(itemi, itemj) === f(itemj, itemi)` ? And if yes, pleas provide an example there an item would be contained in multiple groups?

Comment: then it's simple, expensive but simple: `var groupByFilter = (arr, f) => arr.map(v => arr.filter(w => v === w || f(v,w)));`

Comment: Thanks. Not sure which language it is but I don't think it would work. Does it guarantee that all v,w combination in the created group would satisfy the condition?

Comment: So neither reflexivity, commutativity nor transitivity of *f* is guaranteed, right? Then this will be an expensive algorithm...

Comment: There can be many solutions. Do you want to generate all solutions, or a random one, or one that minimises/maximises something (like the number of groups, or size of each group)? Also, if f(X, X) is false, then X cannot be part of any group, can it?

Comment: Yes indeed. I managed in the end, or at least I think as it is quite difficult to test thoroughly. I will post the solution below when I have formatted it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's how I did it in the end. I am still unsure this is completely correct but it gives good results so far.

There are two phases, first one is about creating groups that match the condition. Second one is about removing any duplicates or contained groups.

Here's the code for the first part, second part if quite trivial:

```
for(index = 0; index < products.length; index++) {
    existingGroups = [];
    seedProduct = products[index];
    for(secondIndex = index + 1; secondIndex < products.length; secondIndex++) {
        candidateProduct = products[secondIndex];
        if(biCondition(seedProduct, candidateProduct)) {
            groupFound = false;
            existingGroups.forEach(function(existingGroup) {
                // check if product belongs to this group
                isPartOfGroup = true;
                existingGroup.forEach(function(product) {
                    isPartOfGroup = isPartOfGroup && biCondition(product, candidateProduct);
                });
                if(isPartOfGroup) {
                    existingGroup.push(candidateProduct);
                    groupFound = true;
                }
            });
            if(!groupFound) {
                existingGroups.push([candidateProduct]);
            }
        }
    }
    // add the product to the groups
    existingGroups.forEach(function(group) {
        group.push(seedProduct);
        if(group.length > minSize) {
            groups.push(group);
        }
    });
}
```

Instead of items I use products, which is my real use case.
The bicondition tests for f(item1, item2) && f(item2, item1). To speed up and avoid duplication of calculus, I created a matrix of all condition results and I use this matrix in the biCondition function.